# Plot with embedded legend and white space

Tags: plotting, legending

It would be nice to be able to include a legend in a plot which has grid lines, but not have the grid lines included in the legend box.  Here is an example with the legend containing those grid lines:

```
a[t_, \[Omega]_, \[Lambda]_] := Exp[-\[Lambda] t/5]; l = 
ConstantArray[0, 5];
plot[q_, legend_, title_] := 
Plot[q, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> legend, Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-0.025, 1.025}, 
FrameLabel -> {"t [seconds]", "F(t)", title}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[14]]

l = Table[
   Style[StringJoin["\[Lambda] = ", ToString[\[Lambda]]], 
   FontFamily -> "Apple Chancery", FontSlant -> Italic], {\[Lambda], 
   Range[5]}];
legend = 
   Placed[LineLegend[l, LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {.225, .35}];

plot[Table[
   a[t, 1, \[Lambda]], {\[Lambda], Range[5]}], legend, "An example"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
     Background -> White] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 However, the `Legend` may be too prominent. I recommend `(Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, RoundingRadius -> 4, 
   Background -> White, FrameStyle -> Gray] &)`

Comment: An important question that has raised to me myself: in the above figure how we can change the length of the lines in the legend. It is so important case when we have several `Dashing` styles, in our plots. Sometimes because of short length of lines in the legends we cannot distinguish different legends from each other.

Comment: @InzoBabaria - Add the option `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` to the `Plot` command. Are those lines long enough?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the additional discussion and improvements in the comments!